# Accessing web pages automatically using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to access a webpage using Selenium.

I use the WebDriver and HtmlUnitDriver classes:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
WebElement element;
```

Then to get a webpage I use:

```
driver.get("url");
```

url being the specific url of a page.

However, this does not work for all pages? When accessing some pages the program just halts and nothing happens. What I'm doing is logging into a web page, buying some stuff, and all that works, but when I want to go to the check-out and finish the order the check-out page does not load.

Comment: Are you sure you have correct urls?Selenium should be really able to access any available website.

Comment: Any difference using other browsers? What version of Selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use some functions like these

```
public  String openBrowser(String object, String data,String configPath) {          
            APP_LOGS.debug("Opening browser");
            if (CONFIG.getProperty(data).equals("Mozilla"))
                driver =new FirefoxDriver();
            else if (CONFIG.getProperty(data).equals("IE"))
                driver =new InternetExplorerDriver();
            else if (CONFIG.getProperty(data).equals("Chrome"))
                driver =new ChromeDriver();
            else if (CONFIG.getProperty(data).equals("Safari"))
                driver =new SafariDriver();

            driver.manage().window().maximize() ;

        }

public  String clickButton(String object, String data,String configPath){
        OR=new ObjectRepLocator(ObjectRepo);
        APP_LOGS.debug("Clicking on Button");
        try{
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getLocator(object,configPath))).click();
        }catch (Exception e){
            return Constants.KEYWORD_FAIL+ " Not able to click on button"+e.getMessage();
        }    
        return Constants.KEYWORD_PASS;
    }
```

Better way is you can get those values for processing this from Excel sheets. I am using the data driven framework that proceeds in this way